# Access FineUploader in Selenium test

Tags: jquery, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to write an automated test using the Selenium WebDriver, for a page that includes the FineUploader widget. Unfortunately the web driver doesn't know how to handle the file dialog that is popped up by FineUploader. The Selenium IDE returns LOCATOR_DETECTION_FAILED when interacting with that dialog box.  Is it possible to script the behavior of the FineUploader, or a way to bypass it in the test script?

I don't know if this helps, here is the jquery that is creating that widget on the page:

```
$(document).delegate("#setupImportWizard", "loaded", function (e) {
    var element = $("#file-uploader-demo1");
    var url = element.attr("href");
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
        action: url,
        debug: true,
        uploadButtonText: "Choose...",
        onComplete: function (id, filename, response, html) {
            $("#importerPage1").html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Fine Uploader specifically.  Once the dialog box is displayed, you are dealing with the OS/browser.  Fine Uploader has no control of the dialog box.

Comment: Yes, I need a way to either script the behavior of that dialog or skip it entirely and hard code the results from FineUploader.